# Group list of dictionaries by dictionary column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need your help to solve the task: I have a list of dicts with the next data about products:

```
    - id;
    - title;
    - country;
    - seller;
```

In the output result I'm expecting to group all the dictionaries with the same id, creating a new key called "info" and this key
must consist of list of dicts with info about product "country" and product "seller", related to each one product.

#### Input data

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Samsung", "country": "France", "seller": "amazon_fr"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Apple", "country": "Spain", "seller": "amazon_es"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Apple", "country": "Italy", "seller": "amazon_it"},
]
```

#### Output data

```
result = [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Samsung", "info": [{"country": "France", "seller": "amazon_fr"}]},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Apple", "info": [{"country": "Spain", "seller": "amazon_es"}, {"country": "Italy", "seller": "amazon_it"}]},
]
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts.
P.S. Pandas solutions are also appreciated.

Comment: What about your solution (or at least an attempt)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straight python solution, creating a result dictionary based on the `id` values from each dictionary in `data`, and updating the values in that dictionary when a matching `id` value is found. The values of the dictionary are then used to create the output list:

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Samsung", "country": "France", "seller": "amazon_fr"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Apple", "country": "Spain", "seller": "amazon_es"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Apple", "country": "Italy", "seller": "amazon_it"},
]

result = {}
for d in data:
    id = d['id']
    if id in result:
        result[id]['info'] += [{ "country": d['country'], "seller": d['seller'] }]
    else:
        result[id] = { "id": id, "title": d['title'], "info" : [{ "country": d['country'], "seller": d['seller'] }] };
result = [r for r in result.values()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'title': 'Samsung', 'id': 1, 'info': [{'seller': 'amazon_fr', 'country': 'France'}]},
 {'title': 'Apple', 'id': 2, 'info': [{'seller': 'amazon_es', 'country': 'Spain'}, 
                                      {'seller': 'amazon_it', 'country': 'Italy'}
                                     ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools.groupby:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data.sort(key=itemgetter('id'))
group = groupby(data, key=lambda x: (x['id'], x['title']))
result = [
    {'id': i, 'title': t, 'info': [{'country': d['country'], 'seller': d['seller']} for d in v]}
    for (i, t), v in group]
```

output:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'title': 'Samsung',
  'info': [{'country': 'France', 'seller': 'amazon_fr'}]},
 {'id': 2,
  'title': 'Apple',
  'info': [{'country': 'Spain', 'seller': 'amazon_es'},
   {'country': 'Italy', 'seller': 'amazon_it'}]}]
```